# Recommendation for the creation of a complex web application

Tags: reactjs, django, spring, api, web-development-server

My goal is to create a complex and modern web application, however, it has been three years since I last developed. I was using Spring API REST for the backend and React for the frontend at the time.
Are there any other more interesting choices for you to consider?
I heard about Django for the backend, what do you think?

I would like to have a frontend that allows me to create a lot of interaction with the user (React?). A backend that allows to provide APIs usable by the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of options to be considered - Spring, Django, Go, NodeJS (and its frameworks, such as Express or NestJS)... and much much more. The choice is actually yours and it depends on your skills and on the requirements of the application itself - there's no clear answer about the tech stack here. Do your research and decide what you want to learn ;)

Comment: Yes I agree, thanks for the answer!
As there are more and more Framework, I heard about "Webflow" for instance, I'm afraid to be apated by a tecno nocode and to be blocked.
We agree that for a complete web application, we must use a tandem of backend/frontend framework and not fancy nocode tools?

Comment: Yup, no major changes here. You can go easily with React on the frontend as it's the biggest player on the market right now and Node/Go/Django on the backend, but I would recommend you two first ones as the Django is getting a bit old :) Personally, I find Go very interesting, but professionally I work with React and Node (Express or NestJS) and I find it a very pleasant experience :)